# Make Android smartphone/Linux laptop wait for event from server

Tags: android, linux, push-notification, webhooks

Whenever a push occurs to my GitHub repository, I'd like to define some custom behavior for both my Linux laptop and Android smartphone.

Github allows to call remote webhooks. It is, however, incovenient to have any webhook exposed to a smartphone or a laptop due to them roaming around different networks, not having a static IP and also not being always available. Let's assume that I have a dedicated server that exposes a custom webhook that GitHub can call: there's a missing link between the server and the smartphone/laptop that I'd like to unveil: how can the server notify the smartphone/laptop to make it do some custom actions? The client may wait for the server in a non-polling fashion and then execute the action accordingly when an event occurs. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach I can think of is using push notification.

You need to setup a server for receiving webhooks and send notification from your server to any device.

Implement push notification service on your server. This service will be responsible for sending push notifications to your laptop and mobile (Android/iOS) when a relevant event occurs. You can use FCM for Android and APNS for iOS.